# Does the total elements in Page interface return the total elements or the size passed in the Pageable object in the query?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE :searchType = ':searchParam' AND STATUS IN ( 'ACTIVE','PENDING')))")
Page<Abc> findAllBySearchParamAndSearchType(@Param("searchType") String searchType, @Param("searchParam") String searchParam, Pageable pageable);
```

I passed "size" as 10 in the pageable object.
I have a total no of 50 rows, for the above query.
Will I get the getTotalElements() in Page interface as 50 or 10, after return?

Comment: Wouldn't your question be answered if you simply executed your query?

Comment: Obviously I thought this through :)
But the project is huge, and local not up yet.
Expecting to get an answer, this would always be the last option though :)